# Circle appear gap at edge

Tags: html, css

I'm playing CSS battle and trying to achieve the result perfectly, but I don't know why there is some gap at the edge of the circle as you can see on the screenshot here: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdTim.png)

I know there is better solution like using gradient, but I'm trying to learn to solve the problem here and improve my understanding of CSS. Below is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #E3516E;
}

.Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.Circle {
  width: 199px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.Square {
  width: 99.5px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.Green {
  background-color: #51B5A9;
}

.Yellow {
  background-color: #FADE8B;
  right: 0;
}

.White {
  background-color: #F7F3D7;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.Transparent {
  background-color: #E3516E;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Circle">
    <div class="Green Square"></div>
    <div class="Yellow Square"></div>
    <div class="White Square"></div>
    <div class="Transparent Square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like anti-aliasing

Comment: Also should your "circle" not start off **square** before you radius it?

Comment: @Paulie_D Not sure what do you mean, I'm still on learning phase...

Comment: Your Circle should be 200px in height and width...

Comment: @Paulie_D I've just tried to change it to 200px height and width of the circle and 100px height and width of the square but the gap still exist and 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no gap at edges. Looks like Anti-Aliasing. I have added a `border` to it, so that you can see there's no gap.

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Circle">
    <div class="Green Square"></div>
    <div class="Yellow Square"></div>
    <div class="White Square"></div>
    <div class="Transparent Square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<style>
  
  body {
    background-color: #E3516E;
  }
  
  .Container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .Circle {
    width: 199px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .Square {
    width: 99.5px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .Green {
    background-color: #51B5A9;
  }
  
  .Yellow {
    background-color: #FADE8B;
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .White {
    background-color: #F7F3D7;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .Transparent {
    background-color: #E3516E;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  
</style>
```

Comment: May I know what is that mean? So there is no way to solve it?

Comment: @Ace its a method to remove distortions and make lines smoother

Comment: I see, but after added 'border: 1px blue solid;' the gap is still there?

Comment: @Ace It's browser's issue.  Every Browser render things differently.  It works fine on Firefox, but you see the gap to chrome. Also removing `background-color: blue;` from `.Circle` will fix your issue.

Answer (score -2):

A conic gradient can do it:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#FADE8B 25%, #0000 0 50%, #F7F3D7 0 75%, #51B5A9 0)
}

body {
  background: #E3516E;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I can see you're an expert. But I'm trying to figure out how to solve the problem by using my current knowledge and understanding of CSS before going to a better way to achieve the result

Comment: @Ace remove the background-color: blue from your code and the issue is gone

Comment: Oh well, I've added the blue background to make me better see the shape before coding the squares. You just reminded me that's unnecessaryBut may I know the concept behind it?

Why the width and height of the circle=the total width and height of the squares but there will be still gap at the edge?

Comment: @Ace because CSS is not perfect, it use pixels and sometimes you get imperfect results due to a lot of factors (rounding, anti-aliasing, bug, etc)